# 16.04 LTS - Black Terminal, Black Borders - Intel onboard graphic card

Tags: drivers, unity, graphics, intel-graphics

For whatever reason I recently added this repository in order to upadte graphics driver:

```
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

After updating and rebooting all signs show that a false graphics driver is now installed: Completely black terminal and drop-down-menus everywhere, black borders arround every window, etc.

Luckily "XTerm" still shows, so I can punch in commands. I want now to just go back to the **default graphics driver** which was installed beforehand. Seems easy enough, but I am not able to do so. Or I'm missing the point of the problem, I don't know.

Purging the repository via

```
ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

as described in the readme of this ppa didn't change a thing.
I also tried the "Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux", but running it just gave me a fully black window once again, so I couldn't tell if it did something or not.

I've browsed a lot of already asked questions but most refer to older ubuntu versions or refer to different problems (e.g. nvidia bugs). And I'm now hesitant to try anything without being sure this is right for my system, as I'm afraid to break it even more.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu in its entirety? Maybe it's just a Unity-tweak I'm missing?

Maybe this will help: running

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

prints out:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Process or Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:501e]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefechtable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
Espansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <acces denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device [...]
```

And

```
lshw -c video
```

prints out

```
*-display
desciption: VGA compatible controller
product: 4th Gen Core Prosessor Integrated Grphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id:2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33Mhz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:28 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000/size=64)
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Got some help elsewhere: turns out there was a problem of some 3rd party PPAs colliding: In Synaptic I unchecked every ppa but the oibaf/graphics-drivers, did "sudo apt-get update" and tried to purge the ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers again - worked and after a reboot: yes, indeeed, everything back to normal.

Comment: Would you mind adding your comment as an answer instead and check the box as the accepted solution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, sure; was looking for some kind of "solved" button, but couldn't find one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help elsewhere: turns out there was a problem of some 3rd party PPAs colliding: In Synaptic I unchecked every ppa but the oibaf/graphics-drivers, did "sudo apt-get update" and tried to purge the ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers again - worked and after a reboot: yes, indeeed, everything back to normal.